# Delayed Response when NSURLConnection is used with sendAsynchronousRequest

Tags: ios, ios5, nsurlconnection, nsurl

Correct me if I am wrong. please easy go on me. I am not expert in iOS.

I tried sending HTTP Request with two approaches.

1)

```
NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection  alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
```

The response is so quick, the time delay to get response is constant.  One additional effort  is  to handle the response data with delegate mechanism.

Hence I approached with (2)

2).

```
  [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:theRequest
                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] 
                   completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error){
                          NSString *strData = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

                          NSLog (@" THE RESPONSE DATA IS %@", strData);
                               UIAlertView *alView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Process Done" message:@"MY Message" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
                               [alView show];
                               NSMutableData *mData = [NSMutableData dataWithData:data];
                               [self parseXML:mData]; // XML Parsing.

                           }];
```

With the (2) approach, I could see inconsistent delay of getting response.

**My Understanding**

Since I queue the block in NSOperationQueue, it is not guaranteed to be executed immediately.

If my understanding is correct, then what is the correct approach so, that the queued operation is handled immediately.

Comment: If you want something handled immediately you need to do it on the main thread.  Anything run asynchronously in the background will not be instantaneous.  It's completion time will depend on the main thread's workload and other background tasks that are already set to run.

Comment: Does that mean NSURLConnection with InitwithRequest runs on main thread? if i understand it runs asynchronously the request right? correct me if i m wrong?

Comment: I use a class on top of NSURLConnection that defaults to background.  I cannot speak to the NSURLConnection class its self.

Comment: No, that doesn't mean that initWithRequest runs on the main thread -- both methods do the download task on a background thread, so I don't know why one would be slower than the other.